# Is AWS Cognito's generated Tokens URL safe?

Tags: amazon-cognito

When the user authenticates through Cognito's user pools, he/she will get a token. Can I pass the value of that token around as a URL address, as a query string for example?

So is the given token URL safe? Will it be any problem with the length of the token?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cognito User Pools tokens are URL safe so they can be passed as parameters in a query string.

Comment: can you support this by a link? I disagree I got # recently.